# CKEditor 4.x configure style of p element as a permanent style

Tags: ckeditor

It's not easy to describe - forgive -
In the moment you start to write something into an empty editor the text is wrapped with a  `p` element.
This default `p` element I want to style with my own custom css style. For instance : `p { margin-bottom: 1em;   color: blue};`

I managed it temporarily by adding `CKEDITOR.instances['editor1'].setData(styleElement)` in an init routine. But then it is applied to the html content and editable.

To get me right : This should be applied permanently and not editable by users. It should be just applied as a basic look.

Any ideas how to apply it the correct way ?

Answer (score 2):

Why not simply use CSS for that? E.g. by adding blue color for `<p>` elements in `<ckeditor>/contents.css`?

If you use classic editor (I assume you do), then it loads `contents.css` file by default. This CSS file gives you the possibility to style content in any way you want in the editing area without polluting the resulting markup produced by CKEditor.

What's more, if you ever change your mind and decide to start using red color for paragraphs in all new and existing articles, you will have to adjust just the CSS file.

Changing style in `contents.css` will resolve the problem in the editing area only. A similar CSS rule to set blue color will have to be added to your website stylesheet so that the HTML content produced in WYSIWYG editor was styled in a way you prefer.

Comment: Is this an answer or a question ? If it is an answer then please tell me where to apply permanent (global) CSS styles. You may have a code snippet. Would appreciate it very much.

Comment: I edited the content.css file now and it works exactly the way I need it. But I am not sure if this is "legal" ?

Comment: You can do this, consider this particular file as a part of CKEditor configuration. In fact to avoid overwriting it accidentally during upgrades, you may keep the style for paragraphs in your own CSS file. Point CKEditor to this file with `config.contentsCSS` http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-contentsCss